# How to have a natural MacOSX .app of a complex python application (including custom interpreter) via a shell initialization script?

Tags: python, macos, bundle, .app

I am trying to integrate a complex python application (with a custom python interpreter shipped along) for OSX. In order to handle a set of issues due to cross platform requirements, I created a .app bundle pointing at a shell script with its CFExecutable entry in Info.plist. This works, and the invoked shell script starts up the actual application binary. However, I have the following problems:

- The .app icon bounces endlessly on the dock, never reaching the "activated" status. I guess it's because the shell script does not terminate. This dock entry has the correct "application icon"
- When the binary executable is invoked by the script, a new Dock entry appears with a generic python icon. This icon successfully starts up and stops bouncing as the application starts up.
- When I try to kill the first Dock entry via Force quit, the actual application still keeps running, as it's clearly controlled by the second entry on the dock.

Is there a way to have this setup behave more naturally? Do I need to ditch shell script for an objective C wrapper? If I have to use a obj-C wrapper (instead of a shell script) to spawn my application, how can I prevent the same spawning of a secondary icon to happen?

**Edit**: note, I am not running a python script. I am running a custom made python interpreter. py2app is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like many use [`py2app`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) for this purpose with success.

If that doesn't work for you, the Java equivalent I'm famailar with, [appbundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler), does create a mach-o executable stub to fire things off. You might check out how they do things, particularly their [`main.m`](https://java.net/projects/appbundler/sources/svn/show/appbundler/native?rev=34).

Comment: No, I am doing it by hand. Our setup is complex, I can't use py2app. I'm not releasing a python script

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, and in hindsight it was rather trivial. In the shell script, I need to invoke my binary with `exec`, so that the running bash process is replaced (*a la* `execve()`) rather than spawning a new process. The only problem is that my interpreter now replaces the icon with the stock one, but I have only one icon in the dock now, and behaves naturally.